# Version and release management without Maven

Tags: automation, git

I'm trying to find an alternative to versioning, release creation, deployment etc. that is not [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven).

Let me explain: We use Maven to build almost anything, Java, Docker, NodeJS, Golang, you name it.

For that we use different Maven plugins like release, scm, and version plugin.
Maven downloads zillions of stuff before actually doing what it is supposed to do. And since we have many build servers, usually the m2 Repo is (almost) empty and so the build takes long time.

I'm looking for a way or a tool out of the Maven crazyness that can:

- detect and increment versions
- create and push Git commits
- support raw shell commands, so that I can custom commands for different programming languages

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't kill me, but: Bash scripts? Or maybe you should distribute the m2 repo before or during the build?

Answer (score 1):

[Jeka](https://jeka.dev) may help you.

It can be used both as a library and a first class build tool.

It features flexible way to release programmatically, especially using git. 
It uses its own feature to release itself. Its release process is triggered by the presence of a git tag on HEAD.
It provides also convenient way to integrate command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/) would be something to look at since it has support for a number of [languages](https://gradle.org/features/#ecosystem-specific-features) and [has faster build times than maven](https://gradle.org/gradle-vs-maven-performance/) since it caches build artifacts and it has support for distributed builds. It is highly extensible using plugins so it can support a number of custom scenarios. Gradle has a great plugin ecosystem so you should be able to find how to get things done fairly quickly.

If you are feeling super adventurous and want sheer build speed , take a look facebook’s build tool [Buck](https://buckbuild.com/). It also does caching and some smart dependency tracking so [builds are faster](https://buckbuild.com/concept/what_makes_buck_so_fast.html). Buck is fairly new so your mileage may vary by the type of language and platform.

Answer (score 0):

[Ant](http://ant.apache.org), but you will need to create scripts to perform all the details.